# UIImage does not change with CGrectMake

Tags: ios, uiimage

I would like to change UIImage according to image size, so I though I would do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, 200, 200)
```

and I though result would be 200x200 image in top right corner, but instead the size of imageView has not changed and is the same as set in StoryBoard.

I also though of making `IBOutlet` for imageView heigh constrain and changing it in viewDidLoad. That didn't worked as well.

EDIT:

```
@IBOutlet var imageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and in `viewDidLoad`

```
imageHeight.constant = 100
```

Comment: You may want to show your code when you tried to set the height constraint in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've already configured this image view's position and size using constraints in the storyboard. Thus, trying to set its `frame` in code is useless, because the constraints override that.

The simplest solution is to set the image view's position using constraints, but *not* its size. The image view will then *automatically* change its size to match any image assigned to it!

Comment: So I should do like in my EDIT? Because that did not worked as well, maybe the code is wrong?

Comment: What I actually said is completely different from what you say in your edit. Until you try what I actually said, you won't see how it works.